# Symfony 1.4 sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter insert new value

Tags: autocomplete, symfony-1.4, jquery-autocomplete

I have successfully implemented Autocomplete field from database using sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter but i cannot a find a way to insert a new value if the listed values are not required.

Everytime i submit a form with new value, it shows me "required" error. It is due to the reason that the auto-complete field has a different name then the form widget.

my widget configuration is

```
'city'                      => new sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter(array(

                                    'url'   => url_for('trainingdetail/ajaxcity'),

                                    'config' => '{ width: 220,max: 5,highlight:false ,multiple: false,multipleSeparator: ",",scroll: true,scrollHeight: 300}'
))
```

Comment: sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter is only renderer for sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice form widget. You cannot create new values with it, you can only to choose one from existing (its just select field masquerade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought there may be a more elegant way of doing this, but i solved it as follows.

When using sfWidgetFormJqueryAutocompleter, the actual form field get replaced by another field from the widget and the original form field converts to a hidden field.

I simply checked if the visible field has a value, and if yes, assigns the value to the hidden field which is the original form fields defined in form class.

my sample code, triggers at form submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).submit(function cty(){
   if($('#autocomplete_trn_training_city').val().length>0)
    {
        $('#trn_training_city').val($('#autocomplete_trn_training_city').val());
    }
});
</script>
```

here : `#autocomplete_trn_training_city` is the id of field generated by jquery widget
and `#trn_training_city` is the id of original form field which is submitted to the database.